# WIN32_FIND_DATA Problems - cFileName

Tags: c++, winapi

i have a problem with my code ;)

```
hFind = FindFirstFileEx( szPath, FindExInfoMaxInfoLevel, &FindData, FindExSearchNameMatch, NULL , 0);

strncpy_s( pszFileName, 280, FindData.cFileName, strlen(FindData.cFileName));
```

everything seems fine but when i copy the executable to another computer (windows 2003) i get 
But for pszFileName i get really strange output

Comment: How is pszFileName declared and initialized?

Comment: is hFind a valid handle on win2k3?

Answer (score 2):

Specifying FindExInfoMaxInfoLevel is incorrect.  The [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364415.aspx) says:

> FindExInfoMaxInfoLevel
>
> > This value is used for validation.  Supported values are less than this value.

In addition, from your usage of FindFirstFileEx, I cannot see why you do not use the simpler [FindFirstFile function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418.aspx).

Comment: thanks very much, the error really was concerning FindExInfoMaxInfoLevel!

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough code to diagnose the problem, especially without any evidence of error checking.  However, there is something really smelly in what you posted.  Your call to strncpy_s() says that pszFileName is a pointer to an array with 280 elements.  Where did that number come from?  Is it just a guess?  It can never be more than 260 on Windows, why is it more?  I suspect that when you make this a *real* number, like an argument passed to your function, instead of a guess that you'll fix the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

You shuold not use the output fields in `FindData` without first checking that `hFind` is valid.  From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364419%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> If the function fails or fails to
>   locate files from the search string in
>   the lpFileName parameter, the return
>   value is INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE and the
>   contents of lpFindFileData are
>   indeterminate.

Thus you should have (after fixing other problems in your API call described in the answers here):

```
hFind = FindFirstFileEx( szPath, /* replace FindExInfoMaxInfoLevel here */, 
    &FindData, FindExSearchNameMatch, NULL , 0);
if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
  strncpy_s( pszFileName, 280, FindData.cFileName, strlen(FindData.cFileName));
}
```